# Display search results on separate page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

My users have scores which depends on search params, i display it on a result page but i would like display it on their profiles

My search controller

```
@users = User.where(id: @biens.reorder(:user_id).pluck(:user_id)).limit(3)

@users.each do |user|
  user.delai_score = calc_delai_score(user)
  user.score_ventes = result_date_ventes(@biens.group_by(&:user), user)
  user.score_final = calc_final_score(user.score_ventes, user.delai_score, ventes_area_size(@biens.group_by(&:user), user))
end
```

My search result view

```
<%= u.delai_score %>
<%= u.score_ventes %>/20
<%= u.score_final %>
```

I want know how display their scores (with data from search result page) on profile page,

My Users have houses,
After a search who select houses in location area and are in params i calculate user scores and display datas about Users
I want get scores from result and display it on user profile page
But my problem is i have no idea how take scores from result page

Comment: i edited my question @pascalbetz

Answer (score 0):

You want to display the `delay_score`, `score_ventes` and `score_final` values on a profile page?
Just set those values in your profiles controller. Perhaps something like:

```
def show
  @biens = WhateverThisIs...
  @user = User.find ...
  @user.delai_score = calc_delai_score(user)
  @user.score_ventes = result_date_ventes(@biens.group_by(&:user), user)
  @user.score_final = calc_final_score(@user.score_ventes, @user.delai_score, ventes_area_size(@biens.group_by(&:user), @user))
end
```

Comment: I want display the scores on profile page but the scores depends of the search result previous page so i cant call my methods to get values, i think i have something to do with search form to give params to result_path and user_path

Comment: please update your question so it is complete, shows what params are missing, error messages, expected results, actual results and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
def search
  ...
  redirect_to user_path(@user, search_key: search_value)
end
```

Then in your users controller you'll be able to access it like that:

```
 params[:search_key]
```

Another option is to save it into cookies